# How to have the *ngFor loop to execute for first n-1 times, don't want last index' data to be displayed?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

HTML :

```
<div *ngIf="userdata; else blank;">                         
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of userdata">                                          
    <td>{{data.Id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Email}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Address}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Role}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Gender}}</td>
    <td>
     <button type="button" (click)="setUser(data)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm edit">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"/> Edit</button>                                              
     <button type="button" id="close" style="height: 30px;"
      (click)="deleteUser(data.Id)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm close" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
    </td>                                           
   </tr>  
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<ng-template #blank>No Records found...</ng-template>
```

This is what i exactly get in userdata Array :

```
[{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "sdfd",
    "Email": "fdg",
    "Address": "dfg",
    "Role": "Admin",
    "Gender": "male"
}, {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "dgfhh",
    "Email": "gdh",
    "Address": "hhh",
    "Role": "User",
    "Gender": "female"
}, {
    "Id": "3",
    "Name": "dfgf",
    "Email": "fgdh",
    "Address": "fghd",
    "Role": "Super-Admin",
    "Gender": "male"
}, "{\"blank-email\":\"Email cannot be blank\",\"blank-role\":\"You must play some role\",\"blank-gender\":\"You must specify your Gender\"}"]
```

so here, i don't want this to be executed from the array:

> "{\"blank-email\":\"Email cannot be blank\",\"blank-role\":\"You must
>   play some role\",\"blank-gender\":\"You must specify your Gender\"}"

Comment: All of these answers will do the trick, but this is bad practice, and if you will change your data model, for example: filter the array to include only valid values, your view will break, you should not rely on the view to filter your data, you should only display it. For better practice, just filter the array after you done loading your data.

Comment: Can't agree anymore on this.

Answer (score 7):

You could add `*ngIf` and render the elements which are not last.

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of userdata; last as l">
   <ng-container *ngIf="!l">
     .....
   </ng-container>
</tr>
```

---

Rather good approach would be slice or dice down the viewModel collection itself and keep `ngFor` on that collection to display it on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy fix** by using **pipe**

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of userdata | slice:0:(userdata.length-2)">
 ...                                          
 ...
</tr>
```

> **Explanation**

**Last element**'s `index = userdata.length - 1`

So for it's **previous one**'s `index  = userdata.length - 2`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best to do is in the controller to exclude that last item. I would consider it a better practice to leave that logic in the controller rather than in the view.

I don't know Angular specifically but in general you may want to use a computed property. A quick search here and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47306546/3494812) with an example on how to do it.

Hope that helps.