# Proper way to abstract property expression in Angular template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

### Repeating expression

I'm having the following component template in Angular 6. I'm repeating `a && (b || c)` expression 3 times, so I'd like to somehow abstract it.

*parent.component.html*

```
<component
  [prop1]="1"
  [prop2]="a && (b || c)"
>
</component>

<component
  [prop1]="2"
  [prop2]="a && (b || c)"
>
</component>

<component
  [prop1]="3"
  [prop2]="a && (b || c)"
>
</component>
```

### Abstracting it as function

My first intuition is to abstract it as a function, a method of the component which defines the template. The code presented below.

The problem with this approach is the performance. The function gets called dozens of times, even when `a`, `b` and `c` values don't change. My worries are confirmed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710642/does-angular-have-the-computed-property-feature-like-in-vue-js#47306546).

*parent.component.ts*

```
@Component(...)
class ParentComponent {

  (...)

  public prop2(): boolean {
    return this.a && (this.b || this.c);
  }

  (...)

}
```

*parent.component.html*

```
<component
  [prop1]="1"
  [prop2]="prop2()"
>
</component>

<component
  [prop1]="2"
  [prop2]="prop2()"
>
</component>

<component
  [prop1]="3"
  [prop2]="prop2()"
>
</component>
```

### Question

What's the proper way in Angular (especially performance-wise) to abstract that `a && (b || c)` expression?

Comment: If you don't need any parametrs a property would be better : `public get prop2(): boolean {
    return this.a && (this.b || this.c);
  }` and in your component you can just use ` [prop2]="prop2"`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: How is getter better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have very simple `test` then you use inline check however if you have complicated condition then it is always better to move to separate function.

Performance wise there won't be much difference in `inline` and `function` fashion since both will take the same amount for execution. There is no extra optimization in either case.