# Add thousands separator in numerical values but only for display (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface

I am currently fetching numerical value from backend and displaying it in the UI by adding thousands separator using the following formula in the html code:

```
value = "{{this.amount | number:'':'en-US'}}"
```

So a value that is **2210044.2** in backend DB is shown as **2,210,044.2** in UI which is exactly what I want but when user tries to save this value back into the backend, the value '**2,210,044.2**' is going to the backend instead of the raw numerical value of '**2210044.2**'and causing exceptions.

How do I code this in such a way that thousands separator is only for display purpose to the user and the actual numerical value remains intact?

Comment: Store the unformatted number somewhere else

Comment: Check out the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710642/does-angular-have-the-computed-property-feature-like-in-vue-js . You can use getters just for display. Or you could cast it to raw numerical when sending the form to backend.